# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, weather-api

I'm developing weather app in react. It's learning project. I'm getting error.

There are 3 components I use.

App.js:

```js
<WeatherApiAddressProvider>
  <WeatherCity />
</WeatherApiAddressProvider>
```

WeatherApiAddressProvider(Context API):

```js
const setApiAddress = (city) => {
  const address = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=7b7503a2aa9ca872738c7213619a72f5`;
  return address;
};

export const WeatherApiAddressProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <WeatherContext.Provider value={setApiAddress}>
      {children}
    </WeatherContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**WeatherCity.js**:

```js
const setApiAddress = useContext(WeatherApiAddressContext);

const [city, setCity] = useState("");

const handleChange = (e) => {
  setCity(e.target.value);
};
return (
  <div>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <select
            className="form-select mb-3"
            aria-label="Default select example"
            value={city}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <option className="placeholder" value="">
              Please select a city
            </option>
            <option value="adana">Adana</option>
            ...
          </select>
        </div>

        <div className="col">
          <div className="p-5">
            <WeatherDetail setApiAddress={setApiAddress} city={city} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

**WeatherDetail.js**:

```js
const [weatherInfo, setWeatherInfo] = useState({});

let imgCode = weatherInfo.weather[0].icon;

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(city ? setApiAddress(city) : "").then((response) => {
    setWeatherInfo(response.data);
  });
}, [city, setApiAddress]);

return (
  <div>
    {city !== "" && (
      <div className="card">
        <img
          className="card-img-top"
          src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${imgCode}.png`}
        />
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">{weatherInfo.name}</h5>
          <p className="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
    {}
  </div>
);
```

As you know, `WeatherApiAddressProvider` throw `setApiAddres` function, `WeatherCity` throw city variable. `WeatherDetail` receive these and get data from weatherapi using `axios`.

The error I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(let imgCode = weatherInfo.weather[0].icon)

Solutions I tried:

- I logged received data(`weatherInfo` or `response.data`) and I saw that this data is object. Then I defined `initialState(weatherInfo)` as object but it didn't solve the problem.
- I created a object like received data in `initialState`. But it didn't solve problem.

I want to show weather representative image and weather details in WeatherDetail.js. How can I do that?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I kept getting the error when I created object like received data(in weatherInfo State)

Answer (score 0):

Change the expression as follows in your `WeatherDetails.js`

```js
  let imgCode = weatherInfo && weatherInfo.weather.length >0 && weatherInfo.weather[0].icon
```

Comment: New Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

`weatherInfo.weather` is undefined at this point:

```
const [weatherInfo, setWeatherInfo] = useState({});

let imgCode = weatherInfo.weather[0].icon;
```

I believe you want to set the value of `imgCode` after you call `setWeatherInfo`.

Comment: Yes, I want this one. Your solution didn't work. I thought this way before. I assigned imgCode in useEffect but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Right here

```
const [weatherInfo, setWeatherInfo] = useState({});

let imgCode = weatherInfo.weather[0].icon;
```

You are trying to get first element of an array that doesn't exist on empty object `weatherInfo` you've just created. The simplest solution for this would be to use optional chaining and change `weatherInfo.weather[0].icon` to `weatherInfo?.weather[0]?.icon` however it's not ideal because you would have broken link to an image.

You could create another state with

```
const [imgCode, setImgCode] = useState('');
```

and set it as you do for `setWeatherInfo`.
I would also do an optional rendering based on this variable so you won't show broken image.

```
{ imgCode && <img
   className="card-img-top"
   src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${imgCode}.png`}
  /> 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed.

Comment: Are you sure weatherInfo contains property weather which is array? You can do 
```
useEffect( () => {
 setImgCode(weatherInfo?.weather[0]?.icon)
}, [weatherInfo])
```
to be sure your imgCode is up-to-date with the object you are getting from api call

Comment: Weatherinfo is an object and contains an array called weather. I cannot access the icon object of the first element of the weather array. I also tried the other code you mentioned, unfortunately it doesn't solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was causing the error:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(city ? setApiAddress(city) : "")
        .then((response) => {
            setWeatherInfo(response.data);
        })
}, [city, setApiAddress]);
```

I refactored code like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(city ? setApiAddress(city) : "")
        .then((response) => {
            setWeatherInfo(response.data.weather[0]);
        })
}, [city, setApiAddress]);
```

I will use State as needed.